# Select node in jstree plugin on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jstree

I'm using JsTree jQuery plugin in order to create an organizational structure on my web page.
The problem is when the page loads, the DOM of the HTML consists only of the root level of the tree (for some reason this is the way this plugin works). Therefore when I try to make some node selected with "select_node" function it doesn't recognize it because he isn't loaded into the DOM.

```
orgStructure.jstree('select_node', $('[data-value=101383]'), true);
```

This is the line of code that suppose to select the node.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `jstree` code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: I've already made it. The tree works correctly, but I can't select inner levels when the tree is folded.

Comment: @mici37000...sorry but i m not getting your problem properly when your tree is folded how come you will select inner levels ???

Comment: I need somehow to make the tree unfolded in the right place in order to show the client which node is selected.

Comment: @mici37000...for this purpose you have to go through complete documentation of jstree ,there must be a specific event to accomplish above requirement...